# Accessing my SimpleXML object

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to test the value of the ErrorCode & ErrorMessage Nodes.

```
$x = '<exe:API_Error xmlns:exe="http://xxxxx.uk/APIResults">
    <exe:ErrorCode>ERRORS FOUND</exe:ErrorCode>
    <exe:AdditionalInfo1/>
    <exe:AdditionalInfo2>1-SX-A-J7A-000-USX00-SSX06-A203</exe:AdditionalInfo2>
    <exe:ErrorMessage>Errors:[Account is not 22, 20, 19, or 9 in length.]
</exe:ErrorMessage>
</exe:API_Error>';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($x);
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($x);

var_dump($xml);

var_dump($xml2);
```

My output is

`object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]`

`object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]`

However I load the XML, var_dump only shows that I have a SimpleXMLElement object. I don't seem to be able to access any of the properties of that object.

```
var_dump($xml->API_Error);

var_dump($xml2->API_Error);
```

returns

`object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]`

`object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]`

I am using PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, the answer involved using xpath.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($x);

foreach($xml->xpath('//exe:API_Error') as $e) {

  echo $e->xpath('//exe:AdditionalInfo2')[0];
}
```

Outputted:

1-SX-A-J7A-000-USX00-SSX06-A203